# Async Controller not returning anything to the view when querying multiple datatable in parallel

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

Why is this Task not returning anything to the view?  If I convert it to synchronous then it works, or if I step through the async task in visual studio, it works also.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Load()
{
    var housing = _db.Housing.ToListAsync();
    var school = _db.Schools.ToListAsync();
    var projects = _db.Projects.ToListAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(housing, school, projects);

    var vm = new ItemViewModel
    {
        HousingTotals = await housing,
        SchoolTotals = await school,
        ProjectTotals = await projects
    };

    return PartialView(vm);
}
```

Comment: What does "not returning anything to the view" mean?

Comment: The view is rendering empty.  No errors in the browser.

Comment: @Scott, yes that fixed the issue.  awaiting the _db.ToListAsync() fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entity Framework can not handle multiple concurrent requests using a single DbContext. You need to await each list before you move on to the next one or use 3 separate DbContexts.

Here is how to do it just awaiting each request individually.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Load()
{
    var housing = await _db.Housing.ToListAsync();
    var school = await _db.Schools.ToListAsync();
    var projects = await _db.Projects.ToListAsync();


    var vm = new ItemViewModel
    {
        HousingTotals = housing,
        SchoolTotals = school,
        ProjectTotals = projects
    };

    return PartialView(vm);
}
```

With separate contexts.

```
private static YourContext GetContext()
{
    return new YourContext();//Change as needed.
}


public async Task<ActionResult> Load()
{
    using(var db1 = GetContext())
    using(var db2 = GetContext())
    using(var db3 = GetContext())
    {
        var housing = db1.Housing.ToListAsync();
        var school = db2.Schools.ToListAsync();
        var projects = db3.Projects.ToListAsync();

        await Task.WhenAll(housing, school, projects);

        var vm = new ItemViewModel
        {
            HousingTotals = await housing,
            SchoolTotals = await school,
            ProjectTotals = await projects
        };

        return PartialView(vm);
    }
}
```

Note using the separate context method you are disposing of them so if you have navigation properties that are lazy loaded you use then those navigation properties will nolonger work. I would recommend using the first method of using a single context and awaiting each list so you keep the `DbContext` alive for future requests using the lazy loaded navigation properties.

Comment: in case anyone is wondering, [this is true for ef core too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async)